# SP 2010 Site Collection Migration to SP 2013 On-Prem to SP 2016 On-Prem to SP 2019 On-Prem | Moving from Classic to Modern Pages

Tags: spfx-webparts, migration

I am new to an organization that is making the move from SP 2010 to SP 2013 to SP 2016 to SP 2019.  These are all on-premise versions.  The site collection has almost 3500 sites.  There are lots of customizations - webparts that include more content editors that point to both jquery and html files.

For testing purposes, a team upgraded from SP 2010 to SP 2013.  Nothing broke - yet.  My concern is when they migrate to SP 2016, and the modern pages are turned on - content editor webpart does not exist in modern pages - SPFx rules.  What happens on those pages where content editor webparts have been used for purposes of pointing to files?  Is there a document for the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016 does not have modern pages. The first step you need to take prior to migrating to 2016 is to run `Upgrade-SPSite` on 2013 which will change from v14.5 to v15 sites -- this often does break customizations, so you'll need to do this in a test environment. Transitioning from 2016 to 2019 will not change any site (though some customization *may* break, just depends on what they are).

Sites are never upgraded to modern. That is a manual process which you can choose to do once you get to 2019.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have been informed that the Modern page feature will be manually turned on; I will not have a choice.  It is going to happen.  My question still is, is there any documentation on developing a good plan to go about and tackle these things.  Like I wrote - I'm new to this organization.  I did not create this conundrum.